# VUE, tabla con multiples V-Select

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

estoy creando una tabla en VUE generada dinamicamente de unos datos pasados con JSON, dentro de la tabla modifico un campo para que se pueda escoger entre unas opciones.

Cuando se selecciona ejecuta una función, hasta aquí todo correcto.

El problema es visual, cuando hago la selección en uno de los Selects, todos los otros cogen el mismo valor, solo es visual, no ejecutan la función.

```
<v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="liniesCam"
            :items-per-page="20"
            :search="search"
            class="elevation-1"
            :loading="myloadingvariable" 
            loading-text="Cargando los datos... espera por favor"
        >

        <template v-slot:[`item.diesPerRepartir`]="{ item }">
          <v-select v-if="item.diesPerRepartir.length > 1 "
            :items="item.diesPerRepartir"
            label="Fecha de planificación"
            v-model = "dataRep"
            :id = "item.zt"
            :name = "item.zt"
            @change="guardarData(item.idLinia, item.merma)"
          ></v-select>
          <p v-else>{{ item.diaReparto}}</p>
        </template>
```

**Formulario al cargar la pagina**

[image: Tabla creada]

**Seleccion en la primera fila**

[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][2

**Las tres filas cambian el contenido**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No sé lo que hace tu función `guardarData()` pero al tener todos tus `<v-select>` con el mismo `v-model`, debido a la reactividad, cuando modifiques uno el resto va a adoptar el mismo valor. Si no necesitas que estos `<v-select>` sean reactivos porque lo que tengan seleccionado lo vas a almacenar con tu función `@change`, entonces deberías quitarles el `v-model`. En caso de que necesites que lo sean, cada uno debería tener un `v-model` distinto.

Comment: Perfecto, este es el problema, he hecho el v-model como un array y en cada item del Select le asigno una ID diferente, después capturo el array y funciona. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Como dicen más arriba el rpblema esta que el v-model es igual para todos los v-select.

Lo he creado como un array y en cada v-select le añado un valor distinto (la id del producto) en el puesto del array, así siempre es diferente.

```
<v-select v-if="item.diesPerRepartir.length > 1 "
                :items="item.diesPerRepartir"
                label="Fecha de planificación"

                v-model = dataRep[item.idLinia]
```